# Shopware 6: Changing URL parameters returns the same result in prod mode

Tags: caching, shopware

We extended the product listing to contain the specific paramter "property-groups" which influences the output.

All works fine in `dev` mode, but when switching to `prod` mode, changing that parameter does not have any effect any more.

It seems this is cached, but why is that, even the URL parameters change?

i.e.

```
/widgets/cms/navigation/67e6a05deae747e984a622c7e94e6881?no-aggregations=1&order=name-asc&p=1&property-groups=385b9ebbfc8e450bac9c4d63052ddf7f&slots=7b2547b253a145468fa35eb684b26a62
```

returns the same like

```
/widgets/cms/navigation/67e6a05deae747e984a622c7e94e6881?no-aggregations=1&order=name-asc&p=1&property-groups=&slots=7b2547b253a145468fa35eb684b26a62
```

If we flush the full cache, the second call works and returns the right result.

We of course do not want to fully disable the caching, so we probably have to *tell* Shopware 6 somehow, to use the new parameter in the cache key.

But we could not find, where the caching happens by debbuging through `\Shopware\Storefront\Controller\CmsController::category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be this:

`\Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Listing\CachedProductListingRoute::generateKey`

```
private function generateKey(string $categoryId, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context, Criteria $criteria): string
{
    $parts = [
        self::buildName($categoryId),
        $this->generator->getCriteriaHash($criteria),
        $this->generator->getSalesChannelContextHash($context),
    ];

    $event = new ProductListingRouteCacheKeyEvent($parts, $categoryId, $request, $context, $criteria);
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch($event);

    return md5(JsonFieldSerializer::encodeJson($event->getParts()));
}
```

Here a cache key is generated which takes account the standard parameters, but not the new one added by us.

You have to listen for the `ProductListingRouteCacheKeyEvent` and add your parameter to the parts.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        // ...
        ProductListingRouteCacheKeyEvent::class => 'addPropertyGroupsCachePart'
    ];
 }
 
 public function addPropertyGroupsCachePart(ProductListingRouteCacheKeyEvent $event) 
 {
    $event->addPart((string)$event->getRequest()->get('poperty-groups'));
 }
```

This way Shopware generates a unique cache key that is also based on that parameter we introduced and the cache collision disappears.