# Shopware 6: Hide product for customer group

Tags: shopware

What event do I use best to hide a product from customer?

I would like to show some products only to a customer group. Normal users should not be able to see them.

Comment: Are we talking about Shopware 5 or 6?

Comment: It is about Shopware 6. Funny, the shopware6 tag is removed automatically.

Comment: "Dear Moderators, this is an other example that the synonym shopware6 -> shopware is not helpful. There is a Shopware5 tag which though is not replaced . Shopware6 and Shopware5 are built on very different technology so it would be great, to remove the shopware6 synonym for the shopware tag" (I flagged the question for moderator attention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with subscribing the

```
ProductListingCriteriaEvent
```

this at least should allow you do filter out the products you want to hide for product listings.

I believe this still would allow to show the detail pages, so you also should hook into

```
ProductPageLoadedEvent
```

and make your customer group checks.

Last but not least, you will probably run into caching problems, i.e. the page would be cached for the normal users, and the specific customer group would get the cached results, which still do not include "their" products.

We ran into that here: [Shopware 6: Changing URL parameters returns the same result in prod mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286934/shopware-6-changing-url-parameters-returns-the-same-result-in-prod-mode)

The solution for this would probably to subscribe to the `ProductListingRouteCacheKeyEvent`

```
$event->addPart((string)($currentCustomerGroup ? 'null'));
```

Also you might need to take care of hiding from the search.

This problem seems to be already solved with a paid plugin (https://store.shopware.com/en/acris84338660411/block-products-for-customer-groups.html) - but in case you implement it on your own, it would be cool if you publish your solution on GitHub :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be available in future Shopware 6 versions as "Dynamic access" feature.